# C Windows API using SetWindowsHookEx() to wait for mouse or keyboard input

Tags: c, winapi, setwindowshookex

I've been working on a section of code that checks for user inactivity and updates a main timer (extending it for inactive periods). A timer periodically checks if the user has been inactive for a set time, if so it then stops the timer and instead waits on the next user input via mouse or keyboard. If there is input, the timer clicks in again and goes back to periodical checks for user inactivity.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

DWORD TickStart;
DWORD TimeOfLastUserInput;

HHOOK MouseEventHook, KeyboardEventHook;

void CALLBACK InactiveTimerProc(HWND hwnd, UINT unt, UINT_PTR id, DWORD current_time);
void CALLBACK FullTimerProc(HWND hwnd, UINT unt, UINT_PTR id, DWORD current_time);

void ExitFunction()
{
    // Output to visual studio console
    OutputDebugString(TEXT("\n\nExit Function Executed\n\n"));
}

SYSTEMTIME CurrentTime(char *ddmmyyyy, char *hhmmss)
{
    SYSTEMTIME lt;

    GetLocalTime(&lt);
    snprintf(ddmmyyyy, 11, "%d/%d/%d", lt.wDay, lt.wMonth, lt.wYear);
    snprintf(hhmmss, 9, "%d:%02d:%02d", lt.wHour, lt.wMinute, lt.wSecond);

    return lt;
}

void TicksToDateTime(DWORD ticks, char *ddmmyyyy, char *hhmmss)
{
    SYSTEMTIME lt;
    DWORD seconds, minutes, hours;

    ticks /= 1000;
    seconds = ticks % 60;
    ticks /= 60;
    minutes = ticks % 60;
    ticks /= 60;
    hours = ticks; // may exceed 24 hours.

    lt = CurrentTime(ddmmyyyy, hhmmss);
    snprintf(hhmmss, 9, "%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WaitForUserInput(int code, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    DWORD UpdateCountdown;
    char ddmmyyyy[11], hhmmss[9];

    // Start the inactivity checker timer again
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(MouseEventHook);
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(KeyboardEventHook);
    SetTimer(NULL, 0, 10000, &InactiveTimerProc);

    // Update the full timer to compensate for the inactive period
    UpdateCountdown = 60000 - (TimeOfLastUserInput - TickStart);
    SetTimer(NULL, 1, UpdateCountdown, &FullTimerProc);

    CurrentTime(ddmmyyyy, hhmmss);

    // Output to visual studio console
    OutputDebugString(TEXT("\n\n"));
    OutputDebugString(ddmmyyyy);
    OutputDebugString(TEXT("  --  "));
    OutputDebugString(hhmmss);
    OutputDebugString(TEXT("  :  "));
    OutputDebugString(TEXT("ACTIVE AGAIN"));

    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, code, wp, lp);
}

void CALLBACK InactiveTimerProc(HWND hwnd, UINT unt, UINT_PTR id, DWORD current_time)
{
    LASTINPUTINFO li;
    DWORD TimeSinceInput, RemainingTime, UpdateCountdown;
    char ddmmyyyy[11], hhmmss[9];

    // Timers continue to expire, so we need to stop it first.
    KillTimer(NULL, 0);

    li.cbSize = sizeof(LASTINPUTINFO);
    GetLastInputInfo(&li);

    TimeSinceInput = current_time - li.dwTime;

    // if user inactive for longer than set time (ms)
    if (TimeSinceInput >= 10000)
    {
        TicksToDateTime(li.dwTime, ddmmyyyy, hhmmss);

        // Output to visual studio console
        OutputDebugString(TEXT("\n\n"));
        OutputDebugString(ddmmyyyy);
        OutputDebugString(TEXT("  --  "));
        OutputDebugString(hhmmss);
        OutputDebugString(TEXT("  :  "));
        OutputDebugString(TEXT("INACTIVE"));

        // Stop inactivity timer and instead wait for mouse or keyboard input
        MouseEventHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE, WaitForUserInput, NULL, NULL);
        KeyboardEventHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, WaitForUserInput, NULL, NULL);

        // Stop the full timer
        KillTimer(NULL, 1);
        TimeOfLastUserInput = li.dwTime;
    }
    else
    {
        // Adjust when to test again for inactivity
        RemainingTime = 10000 - TimeSinceInput;
        SetTimer(NULL, 0, RemainingTime, &InactiveTimerProc);
    }
}

void CALLBACK FullTimerProc(HWND hwnd, UINT unt, UINT_PTR id, DWORD current_time)
{
    // Time has elapsed, exit program
    KillTimer(NULL, 1);

    ExitFunction();
    exit(0);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MSG msg;

    // Start the timer to check for user inactivity (10 seconds)
    SetTimer(NULL, 0, 10000, &InactiveTimerProc);

    // Full time limit timer (1 minute)
    SetTimer(NULL, 1, 60000, &FullTimerProc);

    // Get the time of Program start
    TickStart = GetTickCount();

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    ExitFunction();

    return 0;
}
```

The main issue I'm facing is the WaitForUserInput() function never seems to get called after setting the windows hook with SetWindowsHookEx(). What is the proper way to set up the windows hook to the mouse and keyboard?

Comment: You are trying to reinvent [GetLastInputInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getlastinputinfo). Scrap those hooks and just call the API.

Comment: The only issue with that is it could lead the second timer ('Full Timer') to miss active user time depending on the checking interval elapse once it's inactive. The only way around this is to make the inactive timer resolution small (1 second for example) while it's inactive to make sure it doesn't miss active user input. But that feels like a hack around if we're just waiting on those signals from the user

Comment: *The main issue I'm facing is the WaitForUserInput() function never seems to get called ...*  The [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa#return-value) fails with error code 1428 (Cannot set nonlocal hook without a module handle.) If your hook is in thread scope, set `dwThreadId` parameter to a valid thread id instead of `0` or `NULL`. If your hook is in global scope, the hook procedure is required to be put in a DLL and set `hmod`  to a handle to the DLL containing the hook procedure.

Comment: @rit Both `WH_MOUSE` and `WH_KEYBOARD` have the following in their respective documentation: *"This hook may be called in the context of the thread that installed it."* A corollary of this is, that no code needs to be injected into a foreign process. The consequence is, that there is no requirement for the hook procedure to be compiled into a DLL.

Comment: I'm having a feeling that we aren't told the full story here. If all you really need is to get informed about the user being inactive for a certain amount of time, there's no need for a second timer, nor is there any chance to produce false positives when using [this implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61416079/1889329). So what's the deal with this second timer?

Comment: The second timer keeps track of a set time for the user to perform some work and is the main point of the program (the inactive timer is what modifies it). If the user is inactive, then the second timer needs to be paused, then started again when the user is active.

Comment: If you want to record user **activity**, you don't need an inactivity timer. Just set up your (low-level) keyboard and mouse hooks, and take note of the timestamp of the input events as they arrive. If the time between this timestamp and the previously recorded timestamp exceeds the inactivity threshold, write a new activity interval entry into your data store, setting start and end time to the current time. Otherwise update the end time of the current activity interval. Result: A list of activity intervals.

Comment: My only reservation is having it constantly fire off when the user is very active (which would likely be the majority of the time). I would rather reserve mouse and keyboard hooks for when the user is currently determined inactive, so it is just waiting for the single event instead of constantly firing off.

Comment: In that case, set up your inactivity timer. Once you determine that the inactivity threshold has been reached, update the current activity interval's end time with the information from `GetLastInputInfo`, and set up your hooks. When one of those hooks gets executed, append a new activity interval entry to your data store, uninstall both hooks, and restart the inactivity timer. Either way, you don't need 2 timers.

Comment: That seems like a possible approach. Instead of a second timer could just keep track of the finishing timestamp (like you said) and when resetting the inactive timer either push back the finish time (if it was inactive), or if the finish time falls within the next checking interval for inactivity, then use that as the timer end instead. I'm happy to accept that as an answer if you can display the proper use with the SetWindowsHookEx() so other people searching with the same problem can hopefully find resolution.

Comment: *the proper use with the SetWindowsHookEx()* Do you mean the hook procedure isn't called yet?

Comment: You were right about the DLL because WH_MOUSE and WH_KEYBOARD are used in a global context. To avoid that I should either use WH_MOUSE_LL  and WH_KEYBOARD_LL or just run the inactive checker timer at one second intervals when the user is found to be inactive (and wait for them to be active again) whichever uses less resources